# CppCheck crashing with specific template syntax

Tags: c++, static-code-analysis, cppcheck

in our project (VS c++17) we have a template causing CppCheck (version 1.89 but also some earlier versions) to crash no Windows.

It crashes if called from command line or via GUI. Unfortunately the tool exits in a way I cannot get clear idea why it crashes. Via the GUI I tried forcing the c++ version to 14, 17 and 20 but no effect.

After following up on the file causing the crash I identified the following syntax in header is "the guilty" one:

```
// Header file

template <
    class obj_type,
    template<class> class allocator = SmartPointerAllocator,
    template<class, class> class data_container = std::list>

class EXPORT_OBJECT GenericConfigurationHandler 
{
protected:
    typedef typename allocator<obj_type>::ClientData ClientData;
    typedef data_container<ClientData, std::allocator<ClientData>> TargetConfigurations;
private:
    mutable TargetConfigurations m_target_configurations;

protected:
    TargetConfigurations& get_target_configurations() const { return m_target_configurations; }

public:
    /**
    *   \brief constructor
    */
    GenericConfigurationHandler() = default;

    /**
    *   \brief destructor
    */
    virtual ~GenericConfigurationHandler() {
        std::for_each(m_target_configurations.begin(), m_target_configurations.end(),
            [](ClientData& data) {
            allocator<obj_type>::destroy(data);
        });
    }

    /**
    *   \brief regist a new configuration
    *   \param target_config new target configuration
    */
    template <class src_obj>
    void regist_configuration(const src_obj& target_config) {
        m_target_configurations.push_back(allocator<obj_type>::create(target_config));
    }

    /**
    *   \brief generates target configuration values
    */
    virtual TargetConfigurations build_configurators() const {
        return m_target_configurations;
    }
};
```

The SmartPointerAllocator itself is:

```
// Header file
template<class T>
struct SmartPointerAllocator {
    //variable type
    typedef typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type var_type;
    //conatiner type
    typedef std::shared_ptr<var_type> ClientData;

    //creator
    template<class obj_type>
    static ClientData create(const obj_type& src_obj) {
        typedef typename std::remove_pointer<obj_type>::type src_obj_type;
        return ClientData(new src_obj_type(src_obj));
    }

    //deallocator
    static void destroy(ClientData& src_obj) {
    }

    static void commit(const ClientData& src_obj) {
        src_obj->commit_configuration();
    }
};
```

What I further notice is the crash appears on **loading** the .cpp files and reading/parcing the .h files. Not during the analysis!

If I comment the template definition and leave "not compilable code" like this **the analysis passes**:

```
// Header file

//template <
//  class obj_type,
//  template<class> class allocator = SmartPointerAllocator,
//  template<class, class> class data_container = std::list>

class EXPORT_OBJECT GenericConfigurationHandler 
{
protected:
    typedef typename allocator<obj_type>::ClientData ClientData;
    typedef data_container<ClientData, std::allocator<ClientData>> TargetConfigurations;
private:
    mutable TargetConfigurations m_target_configurations;

protected:
    TargetConfigurations& get_target_configurations() const { return m_target_configurations; }

public:
    /**
    *   \brief constructor
    */
    GenericConfigurationHandler() = default;

    ...
};
```

The difference between **first** and **third** code is only ***the commented template lines at the beginning***.

I tried to escape the particular header file but the tool does not allow (only cpp files)

Any suggestions how to overcome this?

Comment: Probably just submit a bug report to cppcheck

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a bugreport for cppcheck.

Comment: Use analyzers that support C++17 :). For example PVS-Studio ([free license](https://www.viva64.com/en/b/0614/)).

Comment: Hell I posted the topic here and my last 2 lines of the post are the important one - looking for knowledge sharing and triggering discussion for effective and&or controlled use and code scan with CppCheck. So please do not close the topic but focus on sharing knowledge in using the tool and c++.  Regarding "free" PVS-Studio, besides the "free" marketing it is not applicable in my case and I have CppCheck integrated with Sonar.

Comment: Maybe cppcheck doesn't handle `template<class> class allocator` syntax and requires `template<typename> class allocator`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define MACRO to cppcheck (include guard of the header file for example).

Or something more specific:

```
#if !defined(CPP_CHECK)
template <
  class obj_type,
  template<class> class allocator = SmartPointerAllocator,
  template<class, class> class data_container = std::list>
#endif
class EXPORT_OBJECT GenericConfigurationHandler
{
    // ...
};
```

and then

`cppcheck -DCPP_CHECK file.cpp`

Comment: can you provide me an example? I did not see in the CppCheck manual how to define micros in the cpp code so that the code is excluded

Comment: @MladenMilev: Example added.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately still crashing :(

Comment: The CppCheck recognizes the MACRO name. Is it possible the problem to be that the macro is within an included header? Should not be as it should expand the header in the class. But on the other hand it is not compiling so might be processing it separated from the class.

Comment: As frequently, I confound the condition test. should be fixed now.

Comment: That works! Thanks a lot for the help and today I learned something new! Good job! @Jarod42